# ANTLR Tool version mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr

I have been working on a Java Eclipse project that uses Antlr 4.4. In my project, I need to use classes of another Java project that in turn uses Antlr 4.6. as a result, I get the error message: ANTLR Tool version 4.6 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.4. I have no idea how to solve this problem without damaging the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple: use the runtime with the same version as what was used to generated your parser files. In this case upgrade your runtime to 4.6.